# Possible to assign the Length of an array through a function with parameters?

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, assign

I'm having about 4 int arrays that need their length calculated, assigned to them and then populated. 
I was trying to thin out the code by using a function with parameters, instead of repeating long calculations 4 times, but I can't seem to set the length by designating the array as a parameter. I tried something like the code below:

```
for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
if(i==0) SetLength(array1);
else if(i==1) SetLength(array2);
else if(i==2) SetLength(array3);                   
else if(i==3) SetLength(array4);      

SetLength(int[] array)
{
    //calculations for length here
    //int result=...;

    array = new int[result];

    //getting info for populating the array
    for(int i=0; i<result; i++)
    array[i]=some_value[i];
}
```

Most of the code seems to work, except for the length assigning part. Any ideas?

Comment: `array = new int[result];` Why you initializing array again in method?

Comment: That is the only way I know to assign a length, with "new int[nr]". Is there an other way?

Comment: Why not use a collection class [List<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx)  or [ArrayList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist(v=vs.100).aspx) which has `.Add` methods

Comment: The loop with the conditions is nonsense. You already write out the full code for all four iterations. Just write `SetLength(array1); SetLength(array2); ...` (with the fixes suggested by the answers).

Comment: @delnan Srry, you are right. I cut out a part of the code since it wasn't relevant in the example but I shouldn't of typed the conditions either.

Comment: @Chris Hammond I think using Lists might be a very good choice. I'm still a bit fresh at them but I think I might change to that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use a collection class [List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)  or [ArrayList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) which has `.Add` methods

Answer (score 5):

If you need to reallocate the array within method and want it to update the variable you've passed as method parameter you have to make the parameter `ref` or `out`:

```
SetLength(ref int[] array)
```

```
for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
if(i==0) SetLength(ref array1);
else if(i==1) SetLength(ref array2);
else if(i==2) SetLength(ref array3);                   
else if(i==3) SetLength(ref array4);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without `ref` modifier as MarcinJuraszek suggests like this

```
for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
if(i==0) array1 = SetLength();
else if(i==1) array2 = SetLength();
else if(i==2) array3 = SetLength();                   
else if(i==3) array4 = SetLength();      

int[] SetLength()
{
    //calculations for length here
    //int result=...;

    var array = new int[result];

    //getting info for populating the array
    for(int i=0; i < result; i++)
       array[i] = some_value[i];

    return array;
}
```

And by the way, you don't really need a cycle here. For your original code

```
SetLength(array1);
SetLength(array2);
SetLength(array3);                   
SetLength(array4);
```

would suffice.